# Processar arquivos em uma pasta em ordem alfabética

Tags: php

Olá!

Eu tenho um código que processas os arquivos em .pdf dentro de uma pasta nomeada pelo cpf.
O nome dos arquivos em pdf segue o padrão **mes_LinhaDigitavel_nome.pdf**

Por exemplo: **03_03399327665540001013242386801015874620000010000_William Gerrit.pdf**

E o resultado exibido na página é:
[image: exemplo]

Acontece que quando o código lê a pasta inteira, na página de resultado ele não exibe em ordem alfabética. Se fosse assim, todos os boletos seriam exibidos me ordem cronológica (janeiro, fevereiro, março...), uma vez que o nome do arquivo começa com o mês (eu esperava que isso acontecesse naturalmente).
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Como posso ordenar essa exibição? Como posso também exibir uma mensagem caso o CPF não seja encontrado? Vou deixar meu código aqui em baixo, caso alguém possa me da uma luz, agradeço!**

```
    <?php
                // Verifica se o campo CPF foi preencido e não está em branco
                if(isset($_POST['cpf']) AND $_POST['cpf'] != '')
                {
                    
                    // Pasta base onde vão ficar as pastas com o cpf dos clientes
                    $dir = "boletos/".$_POST['cpf']."/"; 

                    // Abre um diretorio conhecido, e faz a leitura de seu conteudo
                    if (is_dir($dir)) {
                        if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
                            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) 
                                {
                                    
                                    // Trata o nome do arquivo
                                    $nomeArquivo = str_replace(".pdf", "", $file);
                                    $nome = explode("_",$nomeArquivo);

                                    // verifica mês com base no digito no nome do arquivo
                                    $mes = '';
                                    
                                    switch ($nome[0]) {
                                        case 1:
                                            $mes = "Janeiro";
                                        break;
                                        case 2:
                                            $mes = "Fevereiro";
                                        break;
                                        case 3:
                                            $mes = "Março";
                                        break;
                                        case 4:
                                            $mes = "Abril";
                                        break;
                                        case 5:
                                            $mes = "Maio";
                                        break;
                                        case 6:
                                            $mes = "Junho";
                                        break;
                                        case 7:
                                            $mes = "Julho";
                                        break;
                                        case 8:
                                            $mes = "Agosto";
                                        break;
                                        case 9:
                                            $mes = "Setembro";
                                        break;
                                        case 10:
                                            $mes = "Outubro";
                                        break;
                                        case 11:
                                            $mes = "Novembro";
                                        break;
                                        case 12:
                                            $mes = "Dezembro";
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    // Fim 
                                    
                                    // Remove pastar e subpastas dentro das pastas dos clientes
                                    if($file != '.' && $file != "..")
                                        {
                                            //print_r($nome);
                                        ?>
                                            
                                            <h5><strong><i><?php echo $mes?></i></strong> | <i><small><?php echo $nome[2]?></small></i></h5>
                                        <div class="boleto">
                                            <form>
                                              <div class="form-row">
                                                <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
                                                  <label for="staticEmail2" class="sr-only">Arquivo</label>
                                                    <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $dir.$file;?>"><img src="img/file_extension_pdf.png"/></a> | <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $dir.$file;?>">Download</a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                                                  <label for="inputPassword2" class="sr-only">Código de barras</label>
                                                    <input type="text" id="copia<?php echo $mes?>" class='form-control' value="<?php echo $nome[1];?>"/>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                                                  <a class="btn btn-success" onClick="return fieldtoclipboard.copyfield(event, 'copia<?php echo $mes?>')">COPIAR</a>
                                                </div>
                                              </div>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
        <br><hr>
                                        <?php
                                        }
                                }
                            closedir($dh);
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    echo "<script>
                        alert('O Campo CPF não pode estar em branco!');
                  </script>";
                  header("location:index.php");
                    exit;
                }
        ?>
```

Comment: Ler diretório de forma ordenada: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18110924/3497987

Comment: Acho  que neste caso você precisaria usar a função [`scandir`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php). Baseando-me [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/541539/12195738) do Stack Overflow (inglês), o motivo para a falta de ordenação dos arquivos é porque a função utilizada lê os arquivos de acordo com a ordem em que eles são armazenados no sistema de arquivos.